# Regular Expression to validate only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, space, period, hyphen - exclamation mark ! question mark ? quotes "

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression which validate the text which user enter.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
```

By above line, we can allow only Alphabetic, Numbers and Space.

What will be regular expression to allow:

alphabetic,
numbers,
space,
period .
hyphen -
exclamation mark !
question mark ?
quotes "

Except above characters user can not enter other characters.

Thanks,
naveenos

Answer (score 11):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 .!?"-]+$/
```

Note that the position of the `-` character is important. If it appears between two characters (e.g. `a-z`) it represents a character range. If it appears in at the beginning or end of the character class (or if it's escaped) it represents a literal hyphen character.

Comment: I already used this expression but I think I was placing symbols in wrong order. Thanks.

Comment: I found one issue that still it do not allow to **enter** key in the textarea. [link](http://www.naveenos.com)

Comment: ok Don't worry. I got it.

Below syntax will allow to use Enter key in the text area with all validation:
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s .!?"-]+$/`

Comment: @naveenos That would also allow tabs and other whitespace characters. If that's okay, you can simplify it to `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.!?"-]+$/`. If you want to only allow spaces and new line characters, use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\n .!?"-]+$/` (and perhaps add `\r` for carriage returns).

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the hyphen  symbol, help me to solve why my reg exp was accepting a range of symbols. my bad reg exp: `[0-9a-zA-Z -_]`

Answer (score 7):

You just need to include this extra symbols in the character class you have in your regex.

You can use this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 "!?.-]+$/
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the hyphen loses its special meaning inside the square brackets when it is the first or the last character.

Comment: Isn't it reverse of this? I mean hyphen is not a literal hyphen if NOT at first or last position?

Comment: thanks for the answer I want only alphabet and hyphen so I have use the following regex, work like a charm

     /^[a-zA-Z-]*$/

Comment: Not sure why, but this didn't work for me, maybe because I'm using in Javascript?? Anyway, I eventually discovered that I needed to put the ^ inside the brackets. Like this: `return str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 "!?.-]+/g, '')`

Comment: `^` at the start of character class negates it. It worked because you are using it in replace not match

Comment: @anubhava Ah, of course. Thanks. Just came across this site that explains it nicely in visual form. One of: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%20%22!%3F.-%5D%2B%24%2F None of: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%20%22!%3F.-%5D%2B%24%2F

Comment: @naveenos: Wondering if this solution worked for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
<?php /^[a-zA-Z0-9 \s\.\!\?\"\-]+$/ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a curly brace to label $MEB$?
Painting with Line Filler
Use of reflexive pronoun in passive periphrastic constructions
Kicad

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33685518)