# How to limit entry to just 0-9, space and comma in an ASP.net textbox

Tags: regex, character, restrict

Please I can't get this to work:
I have tried other solutions [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351942/regular-expression-to-validate-only-a-z-a-z-0-9-space-period-hyphen-excla)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" 
   onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/^[0-9 ,]+$/, '')" 
   runat="server"
   Width="250px" 
   ToolTip="You may enter multiple numbers separated by comma"
   Wrap="False"
   placeholder="Enter phone numbers separated by comma">
</asp:TextBox>
```

I want to limit entry to 0-9, space and comma in an ASP.net textbox

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I want to limit entry to 0-9, space and comma

Comment: @karthikmanchala I want to limit entry to 0-9, space and comma

Comment: @karthikmanchala it simply does not work, i can still type other charachters

Comment: i don't know why you're doing replacing here? just do matching with the above regex.

Comment: @karthikmanchala Your answer is correct, thanks! but before I accept it, why does the placeholder text keep flashing each time I press a key? Is there another event besides *onkeyup* that we can use to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use negated set if you are replacing.. try this: `[^0-9 ,]+$`

This will reset the textbox if invalid entry is found. (Assuming this is what you are trying)

Comment: Your answer is correct, thanks! but before I accept it, why does the placeholder text keep flashing each time I press a key? Is there another event besides *onkeyup* that we can use to improve this?

Comment: I am sorry i havent worked with asp.. I guess you can use some validation function