# validation for a textbox that accept comma(,) , chars , numbers and space

Tags: asp.net, validation

Need to add validation for a  textbox that accept comma(,) , chars , numbers and space

I am trying to add this one

```
ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-z0-9]*(, *)?)*$"
```

but it is not working

Comment: Similar question with answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351942/regular-expression-to-validate-only-a-z-a-z-0-9-space-period-hyphen-excla

Comment: @gkrishy I want textbox to accept comma(,) , chars , numbers and space

Comment: Did link in my prev. comment help you? Just need some small modification.

Comment: @nelek No I tried it but not working

Comment: ^([a-zA-z0-9]*(, [a-zA-z0-9]*)?)*$    try this @rere

Comment: What is "not working"? What happens when you use this?

Comment: @gkrishy I tried it but it is no accepting the space

Comment: @rere then add \s at the end. [After 0-9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked for me.

- **A-Z**  upperCase characters
- **a-z**   lowerCase characters
- **0-9**   numbers
- **\s**    any white-space character
- **,**     comma

I hope this works for you, too

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valTextBox1" runat="server"
    ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z0-9\s,]*$"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid!">

</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```